# Can't connect to Vsftpd Server - Passive reply with unroutable address

Tags: 14.04, vsftpd, filezilla, nat

I have installed Vsftpd Server listening on port 21 in ubuntu server.  I've forwarded a port in my router to forward external port 8500 to internal port 21 where my vsftpd server is listening on.   However, when I try to connect using ftp client, I'm seeing the following message in filezilla,

***"Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead"***

I've read that this has to do with being behind a router.  But I never had any issues with other routers.
Any reason why I am able to access ftp from the outside when using one router but not the other?

Answer (score 2):

FTP protocol is specific, as it uses two simultaneous connections, in opposite to other protocols like SSH, HTTP or SMTP that use only one.

Therefore a NAT code on the router needs some special handling of the second connection in case of the FTP protocol - it cannot be handled just like a generic other protocol. Most routers have this functionality (and you don't have a problem with FTP on them), but some don't (and in that case you have a problem).

There is an option, `pasv_address`, in VSFtpd config file that you can use to tell VSFtpd to present a specific IP address on that second connection, so using this you can work around this router bug.

Comment: This clears up my question.  I guess I will use sftp instead since after all, I do have openssh server installed as well. Thanks.